# utils.ts:900 Matched leaf route at location "/homepage" does not have an element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

`utils.ts:900 Matched leaf route at location "/homepage" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.`

When I'm setting up the routes in my react app, empty page is shown in the browser in the url `"http://localhost:3002/homepage"` and the above warning is shown in the console. What could be the issue?

The respective code for the routing is given below.

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Login from "./components/login";
import Homepage from "./components/homepage";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/homepage" component={<Homepage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;`
```

homepage.js

```
import React from "react";

const Homepage = () => {
  return <h1>Homepage</h1>;
};

export default Homepage;
```

I'm using `react-router-dom@6.7.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below example,

```
const router = createBrowserRouter( 
      createRoutesFromElements(
         <Route path="/homepage" element={<Homepage />}>
         </Route>
      )
);
```

Replace App component with below,

```
const App = () => { return ( <div> <RouterProvider router={router} /> </div> ); };
```

Also change imports like below,

```
import { createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, Route, RouterProvider, } from "react-router-dom";
```

for more help: https://reactrouter.com/en/main

Comment: Thanks brother. I could solve it with your help. The issue was with the keyword "component" in the <Route> tag. When I change it to "element" it worked. Thanks a lot brother !